# How to use Cipher without IV(Initialization Vector)

Tags: android, security, kotlin, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt some string data. I use Cipher. I've been wondering if it's necessary to use IV in order to encrypt data. If you can use Cipher without IV, then how to do that?

I got some code here:
Here is code to encrypt data:

```
fun encrypt(cipher: Cipher, plainText: ByteArray): String {
    val enc = cipher.doFinal(plainText)
    return Base64.encodeToString(
            enc,
            Base64.DEFAULT
    ) + separator + Base64.encodeToString(
            cipher.iv,
            Base64.DEFAULT
    )


}
```

And here is code for decryption:

```
fun decrypt(cipher: Cipher, encrypted: String): String {

    return cipher.doFinal(
            Base64.decode(
                    encrypted,
                    Base64.DEFAULT
            )
    ).toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
}
```

Initialization of Decryption:

```
cipherDec.init(
                Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, IvParameterSpec(
                    Base64.decode(
                        IV.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8),
                        Base64.DEFAULT
                    )
                )
```

Initialization of Encryption:

```
 cipherEnc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
```

Comment: How did you initialize the cipher?

Comment: i'll edit with the post with initialization

Comment: Which mode do you want to use? You are implicitly using CBC ( AFAIK) that requires IV. It is always better to define explicitly your mode of operation as a better programming practice.

Comment: @kelalaka so, as I understand EBC mode is what I'm looking for?

Comment: You need to call it like `val c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")`

Comment: @kelalaka yeah, yeah, but if I don't want to use IV, it's better to use ECB?

Comment: That is really depending on what you are encrypting. The Cryptographers even don't call ECB mode of operation. CBC mode can be fine except it is vulnerable to padding oracle attack if you are using it with a server. CTR mode finds since it doesn't require padding. In general, we say use Authenticated encryption modes like AES-GCM and ChaCha20-Poly1305 that provides you not only confidentiality but also integrity and authentication. So what you want to encrypt?

Comment: @kelalaka Actually, I want to encrypt data of database (SQLite). I wanted to encrypt the whole file, but got difficulties with it(using SQLite Cipher is a bit difficult for me and I got already code using SQLiteHelper :)). So I decided to encrypt every piece of data(which is really affecting performance by the way). So, if it's not difficult for you, what would u recommend me to do? Is it worth to try to recode everything to SQLite Cipher. Is there perhaps any other way to encrypt DB?

Comment: This goes beyond of the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't simply not use the IV (Initialization Vector), as the ciphers working in stronger modes are always designed to require one. The purpose of an IV is to generate different ciphertexts for same plaintexts. The usual approach is to use a strong random number generator to get as many bytes of IV as necessary, than attach the IV to the ciphertext (usually in front of it), and then use the IV to decrypt. Yes, IV does not need to be encrypted or hidden. It just needs to be there.

So what if you don't want or need the IV (you may not need the IV if every plaintext is different because of the plaintext domain or business need). You can use a constant value for the IV (like an array of zero bytes). Then you would not need to attach the IV to the ciphertext. But note - **don't do that unless you know exactly what you are doing**. Use a random IV instead.

Comment: The answer for an IV is really depend on the mode of operation is used and the number of encryptions with the same key. For example, for CTR and AES-GCM it is adviced to use a counter or LFSR so that there is no collision of the randomly generated IV that can have catastrophic results. For CBC mode the requirement of the IV is that it must be unpredictable...